# Set filter criteria in .xls excel file using HSSF POI jar and without using any kind of Loop

Tags: java, excel, filter, apache-poi, hssf

I'm able to set filter criteria but with the help of `for` loop. The following code travel through each row and each column of the excel sheet and do the filter operation. Is there any method that we can directly enable the specific criteria without running into loops?

```
/* Create Workbook and Worksheet  */
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\PNR_AUTOMATION\\match.xls"));
                HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(in);
                HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                /*Add filter on the top row*/
                AutoFilter filter = sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:B1"));

                /*Create list of items that has be filtered*/
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                 list.add("a");
                 HSSFRow r1;
                 /*Loop through Rows and Apply Filter */
                 for(Row r : sheet) {
                         for (Cell c : r) {
                                 if (c.getColumnIndex()==0  && (!list.contains(c.getStringCellValue()))) {
                                         r1=(HSSFRow) c.getRow();
                                         if (r1.getRowNum()!=0) {  
                                             /*Ignore top row  */
                                                 r1.setZeroHeight(true); }
                                 }                               
                         }
                 }
                 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                          new File("D:\\PNR_AUTOMATION\\match.xls"));
                 workbook.write(out);
                 out.close();
```

Comment: What's wrong with a loop? What isn't working with the existing code?

Comment: @Gagravarr loop consumes too much time if the data in the excel file increases. If the filter criteria can be set without loop, it would be more helpful.

Comment: Hang on, you seem to be looping over every single cell in the file, but only checking it if it's in column 0. If you only want column 0, why not fetch only that one? Why are you fetching every one?

Comment: @Gagravarr OK. I will do that. But still one loop will require to check each cell of column 0. Is there any method that we can avoid this loop too?

Comment: Nope, if you want to check every cell in a column, you have to loop over every row to get the cell in that column

Comment: Thank you very much @Gagravarr for your solution. Is there any HSSF method that can directly set values for the filter? For eg: there are four types of data in column0 - a,b,c,d. I only want to show data of type 'a'. Can this be done using any HSSF method?